# Como validar strings?

Tags: php, regex

Eu tenho as seguintes strings:

```
www.adorocinema.com/filmes/filme-226616/fotos
www.adorocinema.com/slideshows/filmes/slideshow-124792
www.adorocinema.com/noticias/filmes/noticia-125494
www.adorocinema.com/filmes/filme-227703
www.adorocinema.com/noticias/filmes/noticia-113312
www.adorocinema.com/filmes/filme-202686
www.adorocinema.com/filmes/filme-144694
```

Como que eu faço uma verificação em que o resultado seja `true` para:

```
www.adorocinema.com/filmes/filme-144694
www.adorocinema.com/filmes/filme-202686
www.adorocinema.com/filmes/filme-227703
```

e `false` para:

```
www.adorocinema.com/filmes/filme-226616/fotos
www.adorocinema.com/slideshows/filmes/slideshow-124792
www.adorocinema.com/noticias/filmes/noticia-125494
www.adorocinema.com/noticias/filmes/noticia-113312
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Pode usar uma parte fixa da string (endereço do site) e deixar dinâmica a parte do id do filme:

```
^www\.adorocinema\.com/filmes/filme-\d+$
```

Diz procure no inicio da linha (`^`) por `www` seguido de um ponto (`\.`) note que ele deve ser escapado com barra mais a string fixa e por último um ou mais dígitos no final da linha (`$`)

```
$arr = array(
'www.adorocinema.com/filmes/filme-226616/fotos',
'www.adorocinema.com/slideshows/filmes/slideshow-124792',
'www.adorocinema.com/noticias/filmes/noticia-125494',
'www.adorocinema.com/filmes/filme-227703',
'www.adorocinema.com/noticias/filmes/noticia-113312',
'www.adorocinema.com/filmes/filme-202686',
'www.adorocinema.com/filmes/filme-144694');


foreach($arr as $item){
    if(preg_match('#^www\.adorocinema\.com/filmes/filme-\d+$#', $item, $m)){
        echo 'valido: '. $m[0] .'<br>';
    }
}
```

Saida:

```
valido: www.adorocinema.com/filmes/filme-227703
valido: www.adorocinema.com/filmes/filme-202686
valido: www.adorocinema.com/filmes/filme-144694
```

Comment: Boa resposta! (+1)...

Comment: Muito Obrigado!!!!

Comment: Faz uma balaca ai so pra ficar mais legal :D
[`(/filme)s\1`](https://regex101.com/r/heFdda/1)

Answer (score 7):

Você pode utilizar a função `array_filter` para pegar todos os valores que forem compatíveis com o regex.

```
$arr = array(
    'www.adorocinema.com/filmes/filme-226616/fotos',
    'www.adorocinema.com/slideshows/filmes/slideshow-124792',
    'www.adorocinema.com/noticias/filmes/noticia-125494',
    'www.adorocinema.com/filmes/filme-227703',
    'www.adorocinema.com/noticias/filmes/noticia-113312',
    'www.adorocinema.com/filmes/filme-202686',
    'www.adorocinema.com/filmes/filme-144694'
);

$valids = array_filter($arr, function($item) {
    return preg_match('/filmes\/filme-\d+$/', $item);
});

var_dump($valids);
```

Saida:

```
array(3) {
    [3]=> string(39) "www.adorocinema.com/filmes/filme-227703"
    [5]=> string(39) "www.adorocinema.com/filmes/filme-202686"
    [6]=> string(39) "www.adorocinema.com/filmes/filme-144694"
}
```

*Note que validei apenas o final da string, desta maneira todo link que não seja "www.adorocinema..." também sera valido.*

#### [Veja a validação do Regex no regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Mais uma maneira:

```
<?php
preg_match('/^(?:http(?:s)?[\:][\/][\/](?:www[\.])?adorocinema[\.]com[\/]filmes[\/])(?:filme[\-]([0-9]{6}))$/i', preg_replace('/([\s]+)/i', '', $odominioface), $resultadodominioface);
if((isset($resultadodominioface[1]) == true) and ($resultadodominioface[1] != null)){
echo "Link ok<br />";
echo "O link do filme é: filme-".$resultadodominioface[1]."<br />";
} else{
echo "O link não é válido!<br />";
echo "Nada como retorno!"
}

?>
```

Agora é só meter um 'array_filter' ou um 'foreach' se for analisar muitos links em forma de array.
A regex analisa toda a url.
Aceita as seguintes urls e quantos espaços quiser nas urls:

http://adorocinema.com/filmes/filme-226616

https://adorocinema.com/filmes/filme-226616

http://www.adorocinema.com/filmes/filme-226616

https://www.adorocinema.com/filmes/filme-226616

Inclui uma 'preg_replace' aninhada dentro da 'preg_match' com o intuito de limpar possíveis espaços na 'url'.
É totalmente funcional. Testei agora.